# Fixed the table header with a scrolling panel

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, frontend

I know this is a duplicate question and I've tried every possible solution but not succeeded. I am using a panel in which my excel data is showing and I wanna fix the column in other words header. Every css I've tried break the panel settings and I didn't succeed. I'm using bootstrap css & have more than 1000 rows that's why I need a fixed header.
This is my HTML

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Excel Sheet</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">';
                echo "<thead class='thead'>";
                echo "<tr class='info'>";
                for ($column = 'A'; $column < $lastcol; $column++) {
                    echo "<th>";
                    echo $worksheet->getCell($column . '1')->getFormattedValue();
                    echo "</th>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';
                for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastrow; $row++) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($column = 'A'; $column < $lastcol; $column++) {
                        echo "<td>";
                        echo $worksheet->getCell($column . $row)->getFormattedValue();
                        echo "</td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo '</tbody>';
                echo "</table>";
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is column and row 1 are for loop, which will give the header. I have used integrated php-html. Other rows will appear in row for loop. 
this is my css and commented code is last code i have tried.

```
.panel-heading{
    font-size: 15px;
}
.panel-body{
    overflow:auto;
    height:400px;
}
tr{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

example fiddle is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adeel1992/286zcrhs/1/)

P.S : Please dont forget to place a comment in case of negative vote for helping me . Cheers !

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle or snippet with working example.

Comment: @P.Frank How can i put 1000 rows coming from database into jsfiddle. I m quite sure you haven't read my question.

Comment: yes i read you example but without see your code is hard to solve your issue. Not need to paste your 1000 row, only three is good. Is just for see your issue in concrete case.

Comment: @P.Frank https://jsfiddle.net/adeel1992/286zcrhs/1/ here it is

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below CSS to your .panel-primary:

```
.panel-primary{
    top: 0;
}
```

This should do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: still break the panel settings and width did not set according to the panel

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with **Jquery**. I check the width of each first `td` for define each `th` width.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  resized();
})

$(window).resize(function(){
  resized()
})

function resized(){
  var widthTd1 = $("td:eq(0)").width();
  var widthTd2 = $("td:eq(1)").width();
  var widthTd3 = $("td:eq(2)").width();
  
  var TDPadding = 11; // = padding + border
  
  var widthTH1 = widthTd1 + TDPadding;
  var widthTH2 = widthTd2 + TDPadding;
  var widthTH3 = widthTd3 + TDPadding;
  
  $("th:eq(0)").css({width:widthTH1 })
  $("th:eq(1)").css({width:widthTH2 })
  $("th:eq(2)").css({width:widthTH3 })
}

$(".panel-body").on("scroll",function(){
  $(".info").offset({top:58})
})
```

```css
.panel-primary {
  top: 0;
}

.panel-heading {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.panel-body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px;
  padding:0 !important;
  margin:15px 
}
.info{
 position:absolute; 
 left:-1px;
}

.table{
  position:relative;
}

tbody::before {
  content: "-";
  display: block;
  line-height: 2em;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">Excel Sheet</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead class='thead'>
        <tr class='info'>
          <th>
            Qc Code
          </th>
          <th>
            Sample ID
          </th>
          <th>
            Date
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            SE68
          </td>
          <td>
            GC57052
          </td>
          <td>
            1/2/15 17:24
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not fully match thead to tbody

Comment: use this example for make exactly what you want. The fisrt row is fixed and is what you want no?

Comment: yeah but you have seen how the scroll is going behind from the first row?

Comment: yes because you have a padding in your main div. If your replace by margin it's work. please try updated snippet

Comment: Let me check and try this on my code. and will back to you. :)

Comment: P. Frank actually i want with out javascript  i want pure css because javascript is not a good solution. The requirement of this is to have a control  on css.